# C# Service doesn´t open script

Tags: c#, powershell

(Sorry for bad english i´m german)
I´m writing a service for a bigger project, the task for it is to check a folder for files and then call a Powershell-Script and give it the name of the file. This part is a bit unclean because i use a Powershellinstance to open a Powershell-Script. The Service itself is working, i tested it with different code to execute and the code to call the Script works when executed by a normal program, but when i let the service call the Script it seems like he just skips that part. The executionpolicy of the Script isn´t the problem. I post the part of the code that is supposed to open the Script. Any ideas?

```
static void Do()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\RecosDienstTest");               // Anpassen (json)

            try
            {
                foreach (var datei in dir.EnumerateFiles())
                {
                    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                        PowerShellInstance.AddScript("C:\\Users\\ZO066\\Desktop\\test.ps1 " + datei.FullName); // Anpassen (PS-Script)
                        PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
                        if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0) { break; }
                    }
                    File.Move(datei.FullName, @"C:\RecosDienstTest2\" + datei.Name);    // Anpassen
                }
            } catch {}
            Do(); 
        }
```

Comment: The file is in your user folder and the service is not running with your credentials so it is not able to get the file.

Comment: Maybe inspect the exceptions thrown instead of silently swallowing them with your empty `catch{}` block?

Comment: The paths arent the problem, right now i´m just testing it on my computer to see if the structur is working and the try and catch is in case there are 2 files with the same Name, because then the service would just stop. The Line where the File is getting moved is always executed, so there isn´t an error that causes the service to jump to the catch.

Comment: "The paths arent the problem" - you _don't know that_ - if the powershell script exits due to an error encountered while operating on the file, your `break` statement will hide it

Comment: In this version of the service all paths are fix. I have 2 folders, if i put a txt.file in one of them the service calls the script and when the script is done, the service moves the file to the second folder. The script isn´t even interacting with the file rigth now. If i run it as a programm the script is getting executed. As a service it doesnt, but the File is still getting moved to the second Folder every time, which means the break isn´t executed. That´s why i don´t think it has something to do with the paths, otherwise I would have the same problem when i run it as a program.

Comment: PS: I don´t know if this got clear but because i´m testing it the service isn´t running on a server but on my computer

Comment: As @Mathias noted, you are not allowing any exceptions to surface because of the `break` and `catch {}`. Since it's just on your own machine, try removing those and see if you can get any errors to throw. You might try running in a debugger as well.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn´t at work so i coudn´t change the code. I removed the try catch and the break but it doesn´t change anything. Without the try catch it ends when there are 2 Files with the same Name, but except for that it´s just running. I also tried to put a try catch around the Powershellpart and write the exception, but there is none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boys, I finally got it! And I feel so stupid now... In the act of fixing this I changed the code so often, used different methods to open the script, I even destroyed my Visual Studio and had to reinstall it. At some point i decided to open txt-files instead of PS-Scripts but had exactly the same problem: Nothing happend and no Errors what-so-ever. The reason is that when a Service opens something, it just runs in the background no matter what it is(I had a few hundred Notepadinstances opened). The strange thing about this, and the reason why I didn´t thought of it: That happens to the whole chain. The service opened a script that opened a txt-file, but because the script was started by the service the txt-file is also opened in the background. I dont know why that is but I´m glad that I atleast found out why the fck nothing happened.